# Vuejs: How can I add additional items to an array that is passed as props?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuelidate

I have an object `location` that I am passing into my form—so that the form fields repopulate correctly.

My parent template looks like this:

```
 <LocationForm :location="location" />
```

My form template is quite large, so I won't be able to show all of it here. However, In my location I am allowing users to create blackout date(s). The tricky part is, there may already be (blackout) dates created, so that array may already have items.

This is what (part) of my `location` prop looks like:

```
// LocationForm.vue

props: {
    location: {
      type: Object,
      required: false,
      default: () => ({
        name: '',
        streetAddress1: '',
        blackouts: [], // this may already have values.
      })
  },
```

My template looks like this when outputting the blackouts:

```
<div v-for="(blackout, idx) in $v.location.blackouts.$each.$iter"
    :key="idx"
    class="space-y-6"
>...</div>
```

The `$v.` is because I am using [vuelidate](https://vuelidate.js.org/) to handle form validation.

I have a button in my form that when clicked, I'd like to add (push) new items into my `blackouts` array. The problem is, when I click the button, I get the error:

> error Unexpected mutation of prop

The error makes sense, I can't add children without the parent knowing about it. How can I allow users to add (push) new blackouts?

Answer (score 1):

To follow up with @zcoop98 suggested, here is another solution.

Since your child component is your form `<LocationForm>`, you can emit an event from your `addNewBlackout` method:

```
addNewBlackout() {
    this.$emit('blackout', {
        name: '',
        ...
    });
},
```

From there you'd need to update your `LocationForm` in the parent template to look like this:

```
<LocationForm @blackout="handleBlackout"/>
```

You can call `handleBlackout` whatever you like. It just has to match a method name in your methods attribute:

```
handleBlackout(payload) {
    this.location.blackouts.push(payload);
},
```

Answer (score -1):

I see you are using vuelidate—and you're already looping through the `blackouts` array.
I like to think of the `$v` element as an *extension* of what the actual data element is.

Meaning `$v.location` can be thought of as the same as `location`. This is where using vuelidate (and probably others I'm sure) is helpful.

Since you have this:

```
<div v-for="(blackout, idx) in $v.location.blackouts.$each.$iter">
```

You can push new items into `$v.location.blackouts`. So if you have a button that when clicked adds new items, you could do this:

```
<button @click="addNewBlackout()">Add new blackout</button>


addNewBlackout() {
    this.$v.location.blackouts.$model.push({
        name: '',
        ...
    });
},
```

Now, my `$v.location.blackouts.$model` will also be updated with any new items. You won't have to figure out how to "merge" an additional array back into your `$v.model`

Comment: This is not a good approach; all you've done is obscured the update in such a way that Vue doesn't warn you about it. **Child components should not modify props**, ever; that's why this warning exists in the first place. Modifying props in a component violates [the intentional one-way data flow that props are designed for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props#One-Way-Data-Flow). Instead, your component should be notifying the parent to make the update itself (e.g. with an event), which will then automatically update the child component in turn (since it's bound as a prop).